# Trying to get Button to copy URL and render snackbar using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, use-effect, snackbar

I'm still learning react hooks. As the title states, when the user hits the button labeled 'Copy to Clipboard' I want it to of course copy the url (which it does), Then I was trying to useEffect so that it will also display a snackbar (from materialui) that tells the user the wesite was copied successfully to the clipboard.

I'm getting the error:

"Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions"

I know it's something about how i'm calling "setopenWebsiteSnackbar" in useEffect. I'm sure there's a simple solution i'm just not understanding.

```
const [isCopiedWebsite, setCopiedWebsite] = useClipboard("https://www.websiteIwanttoCopy.com");

useEffect(() => {setopenWebsiteSnackbar,
    console.log("Website Copied")}, 
    [isCopiedWebsite]
    )

  const [openWebsiteSnackbar, setopenWebsiteSnackbar] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickWebsite = () => {
  setopenWebsiteSnackbar(true);
  };
  const handleCloseWebsite = (event, reason) => {
      if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
  }
  setopenWebsiteSnackbar(false);
};


return (
<Button variant="contained" size="large" color="secondary" onClick={setCopiedWebsite}>Copy to Clipboard</Button>

<div className={classes.root}>

<Snackbar open={openWebsiteSnackbar} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleCloseWebsite }>
        <Alert onClose={handleCloseWebsite } severity="success">
        Website URL successfully copied!
        </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setopenWebsiteSnackbar` is a function.  You currently call that function in other places, for example:

```
setopenWebsiteSnackbar(true);
```

But in your `useEffect` you aren't calling it, you just have an unused reference to it:

```
setopenWebsiteSnackbar,
```

The comma also doesn't make much sense there.  Did you mean to call the function?:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setopenWebsiteSnackbar(true);
  console.log("Website Copied");
}, [isCopiedWebsite]);
```

Basically if you want the "effect" to be that the snackbar opens, then you'd want to call that function and update that state to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the kind reply. That makes sense.